# About using JavaScript in .php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm really actually just a html/css guy.

I want to insert a booking form on to my page but i got a custom link for adding the form. The link consist of just basic script and I'm told to just copy it onto my html file. The problem is i have to add it to a .php file and when i do and reload my page it shows a blank.

I have a basic div in my .php file and a div for calling an image, then my Script. Can you tell me where my problem is?

```
 <div id="dine_oliver_cattermole" class="content_holder border"></div>
 <div id="dine_oliver_cattermole" class="content_holder border">
 <table class="chef_holder" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td width="30%" align="left" class="dine_chef_photo"><img src="/wp-content/.." width="290" height="440" /></td>
        <td width="40%" align="center" class="dine_chef_text">
            <h2>The Tasting Room’s Guiding Principles:</h2>
            <h3>-</h3>
            <h3>Please allow 3½ hours for this menu.</h3><br />
            <p>We do not have a dress code, you dress for the experience you.</p> 
            <p>Only open for dinner Tuesday</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
 </div>

<!-- Start Bookatable Code -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax...."></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://bda...."></script>
<a id="target" href="#">Book Online</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () { 
    $("#target").lbuiDirect({
       connectionid  :  "LITH",
       popupWindow  :  {enabled  :  true}
    });
});
</script>
<!-- End Bookatable Code -->
```

Also got his code to use, but displaying blank.

```
 <!-- Start Bookatable Code -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://bda....."></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         LBDirect_Embed({
         connectionid  :  "ZA-RES-THELIVINGROOMATLEQUARTIERFRANCAIS_283714:67970"
     });
    </script>
<!-- End Bookatable Code 

 <div id="dine_oliver_cattermole" class="content_holder border"></div>
 <div id="dine_oliver_cattermole" class="content_holder border">
   <table class="chef_holder" width="100%">
    <tr>
     <td width="30%" align="left" class="dine_chef_photo"><img src="/wp-content/.." width="290" height="440" /></td>
     <td width="40%" align="center" class="dine_chef_text">
        <h2>The Tasting Room’s Guiding Principles:</h2>
        <h3>-</h3>
        <h3>Please allow 3½ hours for this menu.</h3><br />
        <p>We do not have a dress code, you dress for the experience you.</p> 
        <p>Only open for dinner Tuesday</p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Are you running your page on a server ?

Comment: If you're not using php just call it .html and it should be fine

Comment: There's nothing there that requires it to be a php page.  The only questions I would have are whether or not jQuery is included further up the page, and whether or not the 2 script URLs that we can see are truncated just in the question, or if they're like that in the page.

Comment: yess im running the page on a server, working on staging site at the moment. all the files for website is .php , cant change the format.

Comment: Okay, well that's irrelevant in this case then, since there's no php in the question, so it just doesn't matter.  How about the 2 questions I asked?

Comment: script source was to long so i shortened it.

Comment: VM7461:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: LBDirect_Embed is not defined, my error im getting from this Script.

Comment: Looks like the problem is in the 3rd party script you're trying to use, in that case.  Hopefully someone will see this who has knowledge of that, but there is nothing wrong with what you've posted above.

Comment: @Archer thanks man ,so basically i have a page.php file which is used to hook all the other pages with content. The page im hooking with the booking button Script is not displaying any content because of that Script. i dont know maybe it needs css or fuctions, but my problem is i was asked just to copy the Script into the .html file which is a .php file and its not working.

Comment: They gave me this one aswell to just copy into .html file,

Comment: Then you need to go back to that person and tell them they forgot to tell you something, or ask them for the docuemtation for this script

Comment: Exactly that ^^.  The best test is to just remove what they asked you to add and check that the page works again.  If it does then you need to revisit the source and tell them, *"You broke my page".*

Comment: Are you sure that 2 javscript libraries you included (and obfiscated) are pointing to real files that actually exist on your system or whereever you have coded in the `src=""` bit

Comment: Im just lost in JavaScript, how do i make sure of that? the links does have content if it works im not sure yet. And if i remove the javaScript my page hooks and the displays my content still perfectly ,so i feel the problem is within the way the Script is implemented onto my .php page.

Comment: The browser has a javascript debugger. F12 loads it normally. Check the `console` tab for error messages

Comment: @RiggsFolly, thanks for tip there oops, i deleted the answer, anyway so yea updated my post. Hope some idea of someone may help.

Comment: Do you really wish to include "https: //bda.." twice?

Comment: im actually using the second code i posted, and that one only has one "https: //bda.." and still its not working.

Comment: Do you have access to the log files on your server?

Comment: @PalDev yess i do have access to the log files.

Comment: @Yalma check the log files then. If you get a blank page, it means that there is a PHP parse error but the error output is turned off on your server. Another option: when you get the blank page - view the source. Maybe something is hidden there. The above page does look like HTML only but maybe something else is wrong with the parsing. Tail the last lines of the error logfile, i.e. do a tail -100 /LOGFILE_LOCATION | grep YOUR_SITE_NAME and paste here what you get

Comment: @PalDev Thanks i did resolve the problem, calling the script using an iframe. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@PalDev @Adder @RiggsFolly  Thanks so much, at the end i as you mentioned it looks fine for a html file so i just used the html file coping it into this directory and on one of my page hooks I called the html using an iframe. It called the script succefully.

so my .html file helds the script:

```
 <!-- Start Bookatable Code -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://bda.book..."></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  LBDirect_Embed({
  connectionid  :  "ZA-RES-THELIVINGROOMATLEQUARTIERFRANCAIS_283714:67970"
  });
  </script>
 <!-- End Bookatable Code -->
```

Then my page.php hooks the following page part_page-info.php which contains the iframe calling my .html file:

```
    <td width="30%" align="right">
        <iframe style="display: block; width: 100%; height: 404px;" src="/wp-content/theme/leeu/content/leeu-test/tasting-room/test.html"></iframe>
    </td>
```

This then displays the JavaScript i was looking for.(im just mentioning i think i did not work because all the other pages im not mentioning thats also been called and hooked from page.php has JavaScript interrupting the Script im trying to use).This was my easy solution around it.