# Display a file in another div using iframe in php

Tags: php

I want to display a file in div by giving link in another div using iframe please help me!

Comment: i had a problem using javascript in my php so used an iframe, check this link maybe my sulotion will help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38824946/about-using-javascript-in-php

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly as it will vastly improve your chances of getting good answers in return and not have your question downvoted or closed